# D3Js line graphs - align data points with ticks

Tags: d3.js

In the graph http://jsbin.com/edikeg/98/edit if you notice the x axis tick marks (hours) and data points (circles)  are not aligned correctly. Can someone please let me know how to align these.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear. What I mean is when there is a tick on x axis ( say against 2 AM). But the circle (representing a data point on the line) is not aligning with the tick on x-axis. (you can refer to the graph in the above link)

Answer (score 4):

You will have to be more specific as to how you find them misaligned.

[image: ruler overlay on graph to check the alignment]

Comment: +1 for the graphic, was trying to figure out a way to show they were aligned on my system

Comment: Nice ruler! I think it's an optical illusion that would be fixed by some vertical gridlines. One example here: http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-grid-lines-to-d3js-graph.html

Comment: The ruler comes from this chrome extension. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ruul-screen-ruler/mlbnpnlmfngmlcmkhjpbfokdphfehhjj?hl=en

Comment: Indeed, there is some weird illusion. The circle appears to be more to the left or the right depending on the upwards or downwards direction of the line. Subdued vertical lines would be a simple yet elegant way to address the issue.